# Can't install Apache Cordova plugins in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I created a very simple Apache Cordova Javascript project in Visual studio 2017, and then trying to add the 'device' plugin listed on the Core tab, and then failed with this error:

Installing plugin 'cordova-plugin-device'

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".

No version specified for cordova-plugin-device, retrieving version from config.xml

No version for cordova-plugin-device saved in config.xml
Attempting to use npm info for cordova-plugin-device to choose a compatible release

Done

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error and it was causing because of the path of the plugin where i placed it was too long.I placed it in a folder in E:/ drive and then tried to add it.And it was added successfully.Try doing this.

Comment: Also, NEVER use paths with spaces for Cordova apps. And use paths as short as possible, I use D:\Cordova and all apps are there.